# Is there a way I can prevent users from entering numbers with input()

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, input

I would like to prevent the user from entering numbers to save troubles down the line in my program. I know how to use try, except with int(input()) to prevent strings being entered when integers are required but I was wondering if a similar thing was possible with str(input()).

For example, if the user was asked for their name and they entered, "1994", they would receive and error message for entering an integer.

Comment: Use same try-except with `int(input())` but now consider raised exception as "everything was ok" and successful conversion as "something went wrong"?

Comment: Mind you, trying to filter inputs this way is... odd. Sure, a legal `int` is (probably) not a legal name. But neither is a legal `float`, a legal `list`, etc. Trying to blacklist bad inputs is futile; a white list ends up being tricky because it's easy to overlook legal characters (spaces, apostrophes and hyphens, just for example, all appear in normal names). I'd avoid trying to blacklist specific patterns and just accept what they give you; a `str` that happens to contain numeric digits is no more illegal than the name `!@#$%^` after all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a `try-except` with an `else` block in which you'll raise a `ValueError` if an Exception *didn't* occur during conversion to an `int` (which means the input *is* an `int`:

```
v = input("> ")
try:
    _ = int(v)
except:
    pass
else:
    raise ValueError("input supplied should be of type 'str'")
```

This will catch any *numbers* entered by raising the exception in the `else` block:

```
> 1992

ValueErrorTraceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-35-180b61d98820> in <module>()
      5    pass
      6 else:
----> 7    raise ValueError("input supplied should be of type 'str'")

ValueError: input supplied should be of type 'str'
```

And allow strings by `pass`ing in the `except`:

```
> jim

v
Out[37]: 'jim'
```

Alternatively, you could also do this with `any` and `isdigit`:

```
v = input("> ")
if any(s.isdigit() for s in v):
    raise ValueError("input supplied should be of type 'str'")
```

This checks to see if `any` characters are digits and if so raises the error.

---

You could prevent floats too, but this starts to get ugly:

```
v = input("> ")
for f in [int, float]:
    try:
        _ = f(v)
    except:
        pass
    else:
        raise ValueError("Numbers not allowed")
```

Comment: Since the value from `int` isn't used, you can just omit the assignment and leave it `int(v)` alone. You only need `_` for "not needed" assignments when a name is required (`for` loops, `tuple` unpacking, etc.).

Comment: @ShadowRanger I know, it just looked so bad that I didn't really want to do it (not that `_ = ..` looks great though).

Comment: Is there a way that I can prevent floats as well?

Comment: @Blue_Wolf13: This is why [I was saying not to do this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39613496/is-there-a-way-i-can-prevent-users-from-entering-numbers-with-input/39613634?noredirect=1#comment66534394_39613496). If you prevent `float` (trivial change, just call `float` instead of `int`), do you want to prevent all punctuation? Oh, wait, but some punctuation is okay (hyphens, apostrophes). What about leading or trailing whitespace? There are a literally infinite number of ways to type an illegal name. Ruling out an infinite subset of infinity is not a goal you should be setting yourself.

Comment: @Blue_Wolf13 I updated my answer to include `float`s but I agree with ShadowRanger, this isn't a viable approach to your problem.

Comment: I simply wanted to prevent users from entering integers like 1996 and floats such as 15.9.